# Meaning of a phrase in the Chiddushei R Nachum

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi, text

I'm looking at the Chiddushei R Nachum on Bava Kama 20b פט

Rami bar Chama says that there is a case from the *Mishna* of an animal eating in a *rishus harabim* and being *chayav ma shnehes* that proves *ze nene v'ze lo chasar* is *chayav*.

The Gemara clarifies the case we are speaking about is a case of *"afkurei mafkir lehu"*, and Rashi explains that the reason RBC holds this case is *lo chasar* is because *"sofen l'avod"*. R Nachum makes a diyuk that Rashi must hold the Gemara isn't speaking about real *hafkara* because if so, the reason damage to the object would be *lo chasar* is because right now it is *hefker*, rather than because later it will be destroyed.

R Nachum expresses this idea by saying

> ומבואר מדבריו דהטעם דל"ח כחסר הוא משום דבלא"ה סופן לאיבוד ומשמע מזה
> דרש"י ס"ל דאין כונת הגמ' להפקר ממש (דאל"ה א"צ לזה ש"סופן לאבוד" דהא
> איהו הפקירן לאלתר

I'm trying to understand the phrase דהטעם דל"ח כחסר הוא – it seems like it should say "the reason RBC holds damage to the fruit is not chasar", but the כחסר sounds like the thing being spoken about *is* like a *chisaron*.

Comment: הטעם דלא חשיב חסר הוא משום דבלאו הכי סופן לאיבוד   it is as it is already lacking because it will surely lack after a time

Comment: Got it, thanks! If you submit as an answer I would accept it

Comment: (I had been reading ל"ח as לא חסר)